# How can I add the processing core.jar to a gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, processing

So, I'm trying to make a project using processing, and I intend to use gradle because I like how it simplifies the compiling of the process. In a class I was given a build.gradle that uses the deprecated function compile like this:

```
dependencies {
    // Dependency on local binaries
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

when I run this code, I get a warning from gradle telling me that this build is using some features that will be discontinued in gradle 7.0, I have confirmed that this features are the compile section of the build.gradle . So, I've been trying to include the processing core.jar in gradle using the newer functions of gradle, but i have been unable to succeed. So, how can I add the processing core.jar as a local library to my gradle project using the newest gradle?
thanks in advance and sorry for any spelling mistakes.

Comment: What have you already tried to fix the deprecation warning?

Comment: You should be able to just change `compile` to `implementation` in this case (in both places). But if you like to make a fat jar of your project, you may want to look at the [shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/) to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop using the `compile` configuration.

Instead you should use `implementation` for dependency declarations and `runtimeClasspath` for fat jar packaging.

Your example adapted:

```
dependencies {
    // Dependency on local binaries
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": mainClassName
    }

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```